# ANT exec task with WINEPREFIX

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ant, wine

I need to execute a wine program (on Linux) within an ANT script (build.xml) from eclipse.

Supposing the wine program is in default WINEPREFIX, the following would work flawless:

```
<exec dir="${dist}" executable="wine" os="Linux">
    <arg line="'C:\\Program Files\\Inno Setup 5\\Compil32.exe'" />
    <arg line="/cc 'setup.iss'" />
</exec>
```

Unfortunatelly, due to compatibility issues with other wine programs, I had install that program to another WINEPREFIX.
I can successfully run it from terminal by typing `WINEPREFIX=~/.wine_innosetup wine "C:\\Program Files\\Inno Setup 5\\Compil32.exe"`
The problem now is how to add `WINEPREFIX=~/.wine_innosetup` env variable while executing my ANT exec task?

This doesnt work:

```
<exec dir="${dist}" executable="WINEPREFIX=~/.wine_innosetup wine" os="Linux">
```

Answer (score 1):

...ok found it...

```
<exec dir="${dist}" executable="wine" os="Linux">
    <arg line="'C:\\Program Files\\Inno Setup 5\\Compil32.exe'" />
    <arg line="/cc 'setup.iss'" />
    <env key="WINEPREFIX" value="${user.home}/.wine_innosetup"/>
</exec>
```

the `<env>` tag did the trick!